# Reordering an array of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, sorting, cocoa-touch, nsarray

How can I reorder an array of NSDictionary in this format by the "ordinator" key?

I need to reorder them by the "ordinator" key to show them in a table. In other arrays with objects I used sort to sort using a class property. Can I do something similar to this array?

```
 [
            [
            LogData = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogDataInclusao = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogNome = "Breno Bohm";
            LogNomeInclusao = "Breno Bohm";
            chave = I2017051715323LLNYB;
            chaveNcm = 129;
            date = "31/05/2017";
            defaultPrice = "R$829,44";
            discount1 = "0%";
            discount2 = "0%";
            discount3 = "0%";
            discount4 = "0%";
            discount5 = "0%";
            price = "R$829,44";
            productKey = 17392;
            quantity = 1;
        ],
            [
            LogData = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogDataInclusao = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogNome = "Breno Bohm";
            LogNomeInclusao = "Breno Bohm";
            chave = I2017051715323LFGCG;
            chaveNcm = 129;
            date = "31/05/2017";
            defaultPrice = "R$1.002,97";
            discount1 = "0%";
            discount2 = "0%";
            discount3 = "0%";
            discount4 = "0%";
            discount5 = "0%";
            price = "R$1.002,97";
            productKey = 17391;
            quantity = 1;
        ],
            [
            LogData = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogDataInclusao = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogNome = "Breno Bohm";
            LogNomeInclusao = "Breno Bohm";
            chave = I2017051715323KMPNY;
            chaveNcm = 129;
            date = "31/05/2017";
            defaultPrice = "R$732,75";
            discount1 = "0%";
            discount2 = "0%";
            discount3 = "0%";
            discount4 = "0%";
            discount5 = "0%";
            price = "R$732,75";
            productKey = 17394;
            quantity = 1;
        ],
            [
            LogData = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogDataInclusao = "17/05/2017 15:3:23";
            LogNome = "Breno Bohm";
            LogNomeInclusao = "Breno Bohm";
            chave = I2017051715323JHRYJ;
            chaveNcm = 747;
            date = "31/05/2017";
            defaultPrice = "R$270,44";
            discount1 = "0%";
            discount2 = "0%";
            discount3 = "0%";
            discount4 = "0%";
            discount5 = "0%";
            price = "R$270,44";
            productKey = 17393;
            quantity = 1;
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: where is ordinator key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sort the the array of dictionary same way just need to use `subscript` instead of `property` access.

Sort array with key contains String value

```
let sortedArray = yourArray.sorted { $0[yourKey] as? String ?? "" < $1[yourKey] as? String ?? "" }
```

Sort array with key contains Integer value

```
let sortedArray = yourArray.sorted { $0[yourKey] as? Int ?? 0 < $1[yourKey] as? Int ?? 0 }
```

**Note:** There is no `ordinator` key in your `dictionary` so simply replace the `yourKey` with `key` with which you want to sort your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve  this in Objective C like this :

```
ordinatorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ordinator" ascending:YES];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```